# Complicated reducer logic (React, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have to do some calculations inside my component and they work in this example:

```
let usersActiveActivities = [];
usersActivities.forEach((userActivitiesArr) => {
    usersActiveActivities.push(activeActivities.filter((el) => userActivitiesArr.indexOf(el.id) !== -1));
});
```

But I think it is antipattern to have variables in component, so I'm trying to rewrite it with useState.
Because of that I think I have to use reducer so it has to look something like this:

```
let usersActiveActivities = usersActivities.reduce((acc, userActivitiesArr) => {
    acc = [...acc, activeActivities.filter((el) => userActivitiesArr.indexOf(el.id) !== -1)];
}, []);
```

But it errors with "acc is not iterable".
How it should be written?

Comment: You need to put `return acc` at the end. Plus, I guess you wanna spread the filter results too.

Comment: What is `activeActivities`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @hackape yep it just missed return... thanks!

Comment: Why not use `map` instead of `reduce`? Something like `const usersActiveActivities = usersActivities.map(u => activeActivities.filter(...) )`

Comment: Please add the code of the component

Comment: @adiga yes, that's looks simpler, thanks